# Linkedin JAVASCRIPT SDK is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm using LinkedIn JavaScript SDK to authenticate feature. It is working fine in Chrome browser. But when I open the same in IE11 it is not working. It is showing title in the popup window as "processing". Please help me. I'm using below code snippet.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key:   XXacxm9qaif3kw
        authorize: true        
        onLoad: OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad
 </script>
```

Comment: please tell me that isn't your real api key. If it is, please edit the question to remove it! But consider it to be compromised anyway.

Comment: Yes, it is not actual api_key. Have you faced this issue in IE browser? any help is much appracited.

Comment: I've not seen the problem described so I don't know the answer. That SDK is quoted as working in IE7+, so the only thing I can suggest is to check that your page isn't loading in quirks mode or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. Im running in normal mode only.

Answer (score 1):

Try Turning Off the Protected mode setting in internet explorer. For disabling protected mode in internet explorer go to **`Internet Options -> Security -> Internet`**.There you will find "**`Enable protected Mode`**". Just disable it.